# Is a jump server really necessary when using RDC to connect to Azure VM?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

We are setting up a new Network which includes a VM in Azure. I can connect to this via RDC.

However, our security guy wants me to access it through a second VM for security reasons. In other words, I first connect with RDC to a "jump server" (which is just another VM in Azure) and then from there, use RDC to connect to the second server.

Is this actually adding a layer of security? It seems to me that unless the RDC on my local machine had somehow gotten a virus or gotten hacked, that there is no benefit to the jump server.

Comment: Its always fun to ask the security guys why they think it is more secure, and exactly what they think it prevents. If its a firewall/acl issue, rdp to A then B is exactly the same as straight to B

Comment: just block any kind of access from the internet through the use of acl or security groups. Make rdp port only accessible through your corporation IP or vpn. http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2014/06/04/best-practices-for-securing-access-to-your-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an RD Gateway is a superior solution. It should satisfy requirements of infosec as well.